# shadow rendering incorrectly? Swift

Tags: swift, user-interface, shadow

I have a simple shadow code, and I wonder why the shadow looks like moved to the left side. I also attach an image of that issue [image: image shadow]

I'm pretty sure that shouldn't issue with offset because the width offset is equal to zero. Any ideas on how I can solve it? Thanks!

```
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(hexFromString: "000000").cgColor
self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: offSetHeight)
self.layer.shadowRadius = 1
self.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

Comment: Try to remove those extra properties that you set leave only:
shadowColor, shadowOpacity , shadowOffset, shadowRadius, .masksToBounds

Comment: Where do you call this code? Probably you set up `shadowPath` before layout was finished.

Comment: Oh ya, you are right, thanks! I called it before the layout was loaded

Answer (score 2):

Once you give the shadow radius, the shadow will render to all the directions and not in a single direction. if you want to remove the shadow from the any of the single direction you can achieve it buy emebed it in another view with clips to bounds set true.

Comment: Ya but why the shadows are rendered maybe about 50 points to the left side? It should be for a whole width of that view. Do you see that white space on the right side? I guess there should be also shadow

Comment: You would be loading shadow before the frames of the view are finalized. prior iOS 13 there is a new API viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange in which you can update the UI.